# Should I separate repositories to deal with database, and api calls, or should I just make one?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit, android-room

I'd like to make an app which using:

- MVVM
- Retrofit
- Junit4 / mockito / espresso
- ROOM database
- HILT
- Multiple fragments

Afaik, I need separate `ViewModel` for each `fragment`, is that correct? But what about `repositories`? Should I make one repository for dealing with `room`, and `retrofit`, or should I separate them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as per best practices, you should have a separate ViewModel for each of your fragment.

For repository, I think there should only be one repository. The repository serves data from both local (ROOM) and remote (API) source. Moreover, you might be adding some logic as well, like using local data source, when the device is offline, so having one repository is good.